# javascript conversion from html code to real value

Tags: javascript, html, non-unicode

I have a textbox and i have values in database like ® which is equal to ® .I fetch data and write it into textbox but it writes the data as it is.The code part is like this

```
var data=database_values;//here there is data like this "DOLBY&#174;"
document.getElementById(id).value = data;
```

I want to make the textbox value `DOLBY®` not `DOLBY&#174;`

Comment: As I understand your database value is & #174; and the textbox show & #174; and not (R);. What database do you use? most of them  can use special character set and store (R);.

Comment: @Zoltan Hamori, most databases `can` store special characters does not mean that we have to. There are reasons for storing escaped values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found a way to unescape html code.Here is the function

```
function unescapeHTML(html) {
var tempHtmlNode = document.createElement("tempDiv");
tempHtmlNode.innerHTML = html;
if(tempHtmlNode.innerText)
return tempHtmlNode.innerText; // IE
return tempHtmlNode.textContent; // FF

}
```

Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting ® as `&#174;` then [`unescape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) it.

`document.getElementById(id).value = unescape(data);`

Comment: how can i do that for dolby®?i dont want to unescape omly &#174; ,i want to apply it for dolby&#174;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a server side language (i.e php) there are functions for that.

for example this will work with php:

```
html_entity_decode($data);
```

if you're set on using javascript, there's still a way.
[see the code here](http://javascript.internet.com/snippets/convert-html-entities.html).